# What to remove from a generic chumash to get only the letters as found in the torah scroll?

Tags: pentateuch-chumash, text, statistics

I am writing a program to do various computations with the Torah. To do this I need to remove all punctuation, spaces and other notations.

I have removed the (פ) breaks and all non-Hebrew letters (including nikodot) from the [sefaria chumash](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all) using the regular expression: `"\\(.\\)|\\[.*?\\]|[^\u05D0-\u05EA]"` (i.e. any single letter in parenteces, any non Hebrew letter, any hebrew letters with punctuation or any pattern within brackets - to account for kiris) . However I seem to still have 45 extra letters.

See http://www.filedropper.com/biblestats_2 for the output of the program. Each line has a before and after version of the text. At the end of each book I print out the stats thus far. At the end of the entire file, I print the stats of the entire Torah.

I am getting:

```
Total: Verses: 5846, Letters: 304850
Total Frequencies:
א: 27060
ב: 16345
ג: 2109
ד: 7032
ה: 28055
ו: 30533
ז: 2198
ח: 7189
ט: 1804
י: 31556
ך: 3358
כ: 8610
ל: 21570
ם: 10624
מ: 14466
ן: 4259
נ: 9867
ס: 1833
ע: 11250
ף: 830
פ: 3975
ץ: 1035
צ: 2927
ק: 4695
ר: 18125
ש: 15595
ת: 17950
```

However according to http://www.aishdas.org/toratemet/en_pamphlet9.html and other sources there should be only **304,805** letters. Where are the extra 45 letters coming from?

Comment: Did you exclude by accident the dotted letters (eg. לנו ולבנינו)? Did you include by accident the upside down nuns?

Comment: What's the location of that verse? Luckily the inverted nun is not part of the \u05D0-\u05EA unicode character range.

Comment: Dotted letters are in eg. Dev 29 28, and nuns in the end of Bamidbar 10

Comment: Before: Deuteronomy (29, 28): הַ֨נִּסְתָּרֹ֔ת לַיהוָ֖ה אֱלֹהֵ֑ינוּ וְהַנִּגְלֹ֞ת לָ֤ׄנׄוּׄ וּׄלְׄבָׄנֵׄ֙יׄנׄוּׄ֙ עַד־עוֹלָ֔ם לַעֲשׂ֕וֹת אֶת־כָּל־דִּבְרֵ֖י הַתּוֹרָ֥ה הַזֹּֽאת׃ (ס)
After:Deuteronomy (29, 28): הנסתרתליהוהאלהינווהנגלתלנוולבנינועדעולםלעשותאתכלדבריהתורההזאת Seems fine.

Comment: Kri UKsivs will get you.

Comment: There is a Kri UKhsiv in Devarim 28:30

Comment: @DoubleAA, Shalom: Getting closer [.*?] matches all the kisivs in the sefaria texts.

Comment: Do they have a character marking parshat hashavua breaks? Or sefer breaks?

Comment: Doesn't seem so: http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.36?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all, http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.50?lang=he&layout=block&sidebarLang=all

Comment: Have you compared your letter frequencies to those in a concordance?

Comment: @NBZ, my version has a few extra of each.

Comment: Just a wild thing, please don't be offended: Are there parsha or sefer names?

Comment: @NBZ, you haven't said anything offensive; DoubleAA had already brought that up a few comments above.

Comment: No, he mentioned special letters marking the breaks, I meant the actual names.

Comment: ...sounds like differences between "full" and "defective" spellings of words between the editions of the Text.  I wonder which edition Drosnin used...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are 304805 letters in a Sefer Torah but 304850 or 304848 letters in the text as found in a famous manuscript, the 'Leningrad codex', which many academics use. Sefaria is based on the Leningrad codex from tanach.us. I haven't seen a list of the differences, but an example is האלילם/האלילים in Leviticus 19:4.

Comment: This is quite plausible (the example you bring is accurate). Are you sure the total is 304850?

Comment: No, I'm not sure about anything. Several websites say 304848 and several say 304850.

Comment: I guess I should look for others sources. Can you suggest a more accurate one?

Comment: Perhaps mechon-mamre.org ?

Comment: @AniYodea Sefaria is probably a very accurate representation of the Leningrad Codex. Is there a specific other text of the Torah you are looking for?

Comment: @doubleaa I realized that fact after reading its wikipedia page. Which codex is best for bible codes and why hasn't my link above used Leningrad to compute the total?

Comment: @AniYodea "best for bible codes" Depends what your searching for :) Your link was probably using some other text (likely Minchat Shai's) to make its count.

Comment: @JeremyR, can you provide your sources? I can't find it on Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=letters+in+leningrad+codex&rlz=2Y3TXLS_enUS0616US0616google.mako.occam&oq=letters+in+leningrad+codex&aqs=chrome..69i57.12345j0j4&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espvd=1&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @DoubleAA, for computing and verifying known ELS codes

Comment: @AniYodea You should use whatever text was used by the 'discoverer' of that ELS 'code'. Other texts won't necessarily work. This is the main reason why ELS codes are stupid. Unless you're doing this as a programming exercise, I would encourage you to find something useful to do with your time.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'd like to hear more of your thoughts on ELS codes. Why do you think it's stupid. Don't some mefarshim use it with skips of 7 such as by the Shabbos kiddush, parshat bereishet and the the like?

Comment: @AniYodea It's stupid because the Talmud already tells us we don't know how many letters there are in the Torah because we don't know all the matres lectionis. (Even one extra letter can ruin everything!) If you have a Mesorah from before that time about a relevant ELS code, fine. Otherwise, go do something productive.

Comment: Couldn't you simply skip over the problematic areas or allow for a small margin of error? It's not like every single parsha has these discrepancies...

Comment: @AniYodea Do you have any idea where they are? I don't. Maybe every column has one. Or two. Or three. How do you allow for a small margin or error? Even one letter off ruins the whole ELS.

Comment: @DoubleAA, couldn't you use the same argument against using gematrias?

Comment: @DoubleAA, what's the location in the Talmud that mentions that we don't know how many letters there are?

Comment: @AniYodea Kiddushin 30a.